# Can I preserve an Excel template's formatting

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel template in my Solution with various formatting applied to it for Dates (dd-mmm-yy), text (left aligned) and numbers (#,##0.0)

If I now use code to move data from `SQL-Server` into this template I'm using code such as the following:

Input parameter of `DataTable dt` feeds into a method which ultimately executes the following:

```
string data = null;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
   for(j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++) {
        data = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = data;
   }
}
```

The problem with the above is that all the numbers and dates are being cast to strings and then moved into the template - so the templates formatting will be lost.

Is there a way of moving the data and preserving the template's formatting ?
Or do I need to move the data as strings and then apply formatting after the data has moved?

Comment: Not having worked with C#, but can't you just assign `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j]` - or do you explicitly need to cast it? If the latter, is there any data type similar to `Variant`that allows, both strings and numbers?

Comment: @PeterAlbert I'm new(ish) to `c#` ...it's a lot more stongly typed than say `VBA` - I'll give you suggestion a go though.

Comment: Try setting the cells value explicitly and see if that preserves the formatting: `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value = data;`

Comment: @StuartDunkeld - will try ; that looks promising

Comment: @StuartDunkeld seems to work ok - why not add your comment as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the cells' value explicitly that should preserve the formatting:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value = data;
```